# Excel pause/time wait macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following function on my excel spreadsheet that makes it say "trade" whenever a certain spread between 2 future contracts occurs:

```
Function SayIt(c As Boolean, s As String)
If c Then Application.Speech.Speak s
SayIt = c
End Function
```

Then on the Sheet i have:

```
=SayIt(D15<=G6;REPT("trade ";1))
```

This works great and it will say "trade" but everytime the price moves inside the arbitrage range it will repeat "trade, trade, trade, trade..."

Now what i need is a function that will either make it stop saying "trade" while the prices allow the spread arbitrage or that it will only repeat after 20 seconds or 1 minute if it is still inside the set spread.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for this question, it's made my morning better because all I can think of is Buzz Lightyear getting punched in the face in the movie _Toy Story_ "Buzz, Buzz, Buzz Lightyear to the rescue!"...but seriously Can you use a helper cell and a click event to acknowledge an alarm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question! ........the code needs to "remember" that the previous call was given *True* to avoid re-speaking.  We can do this with a Global Boolean:

In a Standard module:

```
Public Was_c_TrueBefore As Boolean

Function SayIt(c As Boolean, s As String)
    If c And Not Was_c_TrueBefore Then
        Application.Speech.Speak s
        Was_c_TrueBefore = True
    End If
    If Not c Then
        Was_c_TrueBefore = False
    End If
    SayIt = c
End Function
```

Because there is only one Global, this will only work for one function call.

Comment: use `Static` instead of *Public*, and move the variable inside the function: `Static Was_c_TrueBefore As Boolean`. This will allow you to not worry about declarations overlapping, and only having 1 function you can use the flag in.

Comment: @user3778967  Did you see **Sean Cheshire's** comment??